Как понять что моя модель базы данных относится к 3 нормальной форме?
У меня есть 6 таблиц:
По определению она находится во второй нормальной форме.
ни один неключевой атрибут базы данных не находится в транзитивной функциональной зависимости от потенциального ключа. В таблице Студенты есть  столбцы Специальность_ID и Факультет, я считаю что Факультет зависит от Специальность_ID, тк в таблице Специальностей есть такая зависимость. Правильно ли это предположение или все таблицы считаются независимыми друг от друга.

Факультет из студента надо убрать, т.к. он уже в специальности.
Паспорт преподавателя и номер студенческого можно задать как ключи от таблицы и избавиться от id.
Все поля которые предоставляют выбор (предмет, факультет, должность и т.д.) должны быть вынесены в отдельные таблицы, т.к. они типовые, они будут состоять из двух полей ключ и значение.
ФИО надо разбить на три поля где отчество не обязательно.

При исправлении этих ошибок таблица станет относится к третьей нормальной форме?

@Антон да вынесение типовых данных в отдельные таблицы и разбиение комплексных данных на более мелкие по сути и есть вся нормализация. Про замену id на уникальный обязательный тип, это скорее хороший тон чем нормализация

@Антон просто можешь взять за правило, что все данные которые можно представить в программе в качестве выпадающего списка должны быть в отдельных таблицах

Спасибо большое за помощь и ответ!
